# How to count lines which have only newline character on line?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I want to `grep` and count lines that only consist from newline character.
I tried:

```
grep -cx '\n' file.txt
```

but this didn't work for me.

Example of `file.txt`:

```
a
bb

c
ddd

wwfs
```

The result should be 2.

Answer (score 3):

You want to count empty line then:

```
$ grep -c '^$' file
2
```

Or with no regular expressions needed:

```
$ fgrep -xc '' file
2
```

Or with `awk`:

```
$ awk '!NF{c++}END{print c}' file
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use this:

```
grep -c '^$' your.file
```

It matches lines with no content in it (from start `^` to end `$`) and prints the number of matches (`-c`)

Comment: I spent you an upvote. I must admit that I had `egrep` before

Comment: (I said before: deleting mine, as yours ended up being like mine). Yes, yes, but with `wc` :)

Comment: yes.. I just wanted post something I'm 100% sure first.. Had to look in the man for `-c` ... :)

Comment: No problem, now it is fine. With `wc -l` it also was, although I prefer `grep -c`.

Comment: @fedorqui yes, of course. Especially when there is much data which had to be piped into `wc` otherwise

Comment: @fedorqui Watched your profile.. Now you have `666` answers again ;)

Comment: Oooh now you discovered the `real` reason I deleted my answer :) It will be difficult to stay on this number!